# Проверка наличия данных хотя бы в одном поле, как реализовать?

Tags: php, wordpress

Друзья, в своем Wordpress, я проверяю наличие данных в мета-поле таким образом:

```
<? php if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-phone', true) ) : ?>
<p> Поле заполнено </p>
<? endif; ?>
```

Но у меня есть три поля. Как организовать логику : показать контент, если заполнено хотя бы одно поле из трех?
wpcf-phone, wpcf-adress, wpcf-site

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.logical.php ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно получить все мета-поля и применить логические операторы:

```
<?php $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, '', true) ?>
<?php if ($meta['wpcf-phone'] || $meta['wpcf-address'] || $meta['wpcf-site']): ?>
  Что-то заполнено
<?php endif?>
```

Во избежание `Notice` обращения к полям придётся завернуть в `!empty($meta[$key])`

Если не важно чем заполнены поля(главное, что не null), можно применить оператор coalesce:
`if ($meta['wcpf-phone'] ?? $meta['wcpf-address'] ?? $meta['wcpf-site']):`

С тремя вызовами `get_post_meta` можно поступить аналогичным образом.